# Using SSH keys with multiple computers

Tags: ssh

I have three computers: Windows desktop, Linux notebook and Macbook. From any of this computers I am connecting to my servers using SSH. To connect to remote server I use SSH-keys.

What is your approach to work in this case? Do you create separate SSH keys to each machine or use one pair of keys on each machine. If the answer is the second one where do you keep them and how do you deploy them on new notebooks/computers you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Can you use the same private key from multiple devices?

Yes.

There is no technical limitation on the number of devices where you can install and use the same private key.

## Should you re-use private keys or generate a new key-pair for each device?

Although I am of the opinion that **you authenticate to prove your identity** and **your identity is not tied to the device that you're currently using** setting up new private keys for every system you use may be a good strategy. That may  for instance help you keep access to work systems separate from other activities and prevent a cross-over from using a "work" laptop for your private projects and logging in to work from the family PC.

Using the **same private key from multiple devices** has a big advantage on ease of use, add the private key once on the new system and you're set up to access every remote system without further effort. It is also a convenient back-up when one system might break.

The more places where your private key is stored, the higher the risk of a compromise. The fewer keys you use, the more impact a compromised key may have.

You mostly mitigate that risk by securing your private key with a passphrase. (Which you should do regardless.)

To **copy the shared private key** from work station or laptop to another:

- When you can (temporarily) run an ssh server on the new workstation:
  Since there is no particular requirement to keep  public key private: send the public key to the new workstation via any means, add it to the `~/.authorized_keys` file and, using the private key to authenticate from an existing workstation, copy the private key over ssh to your new workstation (and optionally disable sshd again).
- Copy the password protected private key to a USB thumb drive (or similar removable media) and wipe that afterwards.

When using **separate private keys for each device**, but you use all devices to authenticate to the same remote systems:

- send the public keys of each workstation to the others via any means. (Note again that there is no particular requirement to keep a public key private.)
- Use the trusted private key on an existing workstation to copy and add the new public key to all remote systems (with for instance `ssh-copy-id -i new_key.pub`)
  (All systems I use allow me to use multiple public keys with a single account, but that may not universally be the case though)
- When setting up authentication on new systems, add the public keys for all private keys that you're using, not just the public key associated with the workstation you're currently using.